# Not able to auto generate cloud endpoint class in google app engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm new to GAE and facing this problem.
The option `Google -> Generate Cloud Endpoint class` is missing in my eclipse mars 2 IDE. I have attributed my entity class as for jdo, but when I right click on the class, the "Google" option is missing. Can anyone please help.
I'm using Gae plugin 1.9.36

This is my class description:
[image: This is my class description]